# Comparing two Dataframes with diff length to find difference in specific column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nested-loops, numpy-ndarray

i have 2 dataframes have same columns with different len.

```
in [1] : df_g = pd.DataFrame([['EDC_TRAING_NO', 'EDU_T_N', 'NUMVER', '20'],
               ['EDC_TRAING_NAME', 'EDU_T_NM', 'VARCHAR', '40'],
               ['EDC_TRAING_ST', 'EDU_T_SD', 'DATETIME', '15'],
               ['EDC_TRAING_END', 'EDU_T_ED', 'DATETIME', '15'],
               ['EDC_PLACE_NM', 'EDU_P_NM', 'VARCHAR2', '40'],
               ['ONLINE_REQST_POSBL_AT', 'ONLINE_R_P_A', 'VARCHAR2', '1']],
              columns=['NAME', 'ID', 'TYPE', 'LEN'])

in [2] : df_n = pd.DataFrame([['EDC_TRAING_NO', 'EDU_TR_N', 'NUMVER', '20'],
               ['EDC_TRAING_NAME', 'EDU_TR_NM', 'VARCHAR', '20'],
               ['EDC_TRAING_ST', 'EDU_TR_SD', 'DATETIME', '15'],
               ['EDC_TRAING_END', 'EDU_T_ED', 'DATETIME', '15'],
               ['EDC_PLACE_NM', 'EDU_PL_NM', 'VARCHAR2', '40'],
               ['ONLINE_REQST_POSBL_AT', 'ONLINE_REQ_P_A', 'VARCHAR2', '1']],
              columns=['NAME', 'ID', 'TYPE', 'LEN'])
```

the reuslt i want to get:

```
result = pd.DataFrame([['EDC_TRAING_NO', 'EDU_TR_N', 'NUMVER', '20'],
                   ['EDC_TRAING_ST', 'EDU_TR_SD', 'DATETIME', '15'],
                   ['EDC_TRAING_END', 'EDU_T_ED', 'DATETIME', '15'],
                   ['EDC_PLACE_NM', 'EDU_PL_NM', 'VARCHAR2', '40'],
                   ['ONLINE_REQST_POSBL_AT', 'ONLINE_REQ_P_A', 'VARCHAR2', '1']],
                  columns=['NAME', 'ID', 'TYPE', 'LEN'])
```

and each df have length like this.

```
len(df_g) : 1000
len(df_n) : 5000
```

each dataframe has column named '**name**, **id**, **type**, **len**'

i need to check those columns(name,type,len) in each df to compare '**id**' column whether it has same value or not.

so i tried like this.

```
for i in g.index:
    for j in n.index:
        g = g.iloc[i].values
        # make it to ndarray
        g_Str = g[0] + g[2] + g[3]
        # make it to str for pivot
        n = n.iloc[j].values
        n_Str = n[0] + str(n[2]) + str(n[3])
        # comparing and check two df
        if g_Str == n_Str and g[1] != n[1]:
            print(i, j)
            print(g[0])
```

I have above code for 2 different length DataFrame.
first i tried with 'iterrows()' for comparing those two df,
but it took too much time.(very slow)

i looked up for other ways to make it work better performance.

possible ways i found

- option1
  transform df to dict with to_dict() / compare those in nested for-loop
- option2
  transform df.series to ndarray / compare those  in nested for-loop

is there any other better option?
or any option to not using nested for-loop?

thx.

Comment: kindly provide sample data frame, with expected output. Kindly ensure it is a reproducible example

Comment: it's my first time to ask a question, sry for that i missed those items u said. i want to modify the Question but it looks like there no button or something for it// found it. thx

Comment: you are looking for the same value or different ? I mean id is the same or not.

Comment: @simpleApp i'm looking for id where it has different value from original(df_g) one when other columns have same value

Comment: thanks. pls, review the answer I have posted it would give the required rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html),
and if you are looking for records where ids do mismatch then the following is one way of achieving it:

```
r1=df_g.merge(df_n,on=['NAME', 'TYPE', 'LEN'],how='inner').query('ID_x != ID_y').rename(columns={'ID_x': 'ID'}).drop('ID_y', 1)
```

I have used how="inner" join, but based on need can use any of the following joins:
{‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’, ‘cross’}, default ‘inner’

Comment: thx a lot! you're my actual life saver. it worked perfectly. i mean, my original code took 2~3 min for process, yours was finished in the blink of an eye... BIG THX

Comment: you are very welcome! thanks for supplying all the test data prep so I just did was merge! glad that it helped.

Comment: @simpleApp you can change the suffixes in merge to `('', '_y')`, thus no need to rename `ID_x` afterwards ;)